# TypeScript duplication issue on Mac only (webpack compilation)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, node-modules, typescript2.0

I have an TypeScript app. 
I compile with webpack, and under Windows I don't have any issue.
Under MacOS, I have thousands errors because of `node_modules` folder.

Can you help me understand why I can compile on Windows but not on MacOS ?

My package version are the same on both OS : `TypeScript 2.1.1`, `Webpack 1.13.3`, and modules have the exact same version with the help of the `yarn.lock`.

Here the `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Here the `webpack.config.js` :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': [
            'core-js/client/shim.min.js',
            'zone.js/dist/zone',
            './src/app/main.ts'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: './www',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.component.ts$/, loader: 'ts!angular2-template'},
            {test: /\.ts$/, exclude: /\.component.ts$/, loader: 'ts'},
            {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw'}
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            output: {
                comments: false
            },
            minimize: true
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en-gb\.js|fr\.js/)
    ]
};
```

Here the beginning of `webpack` output (few lines because there are 10300 lines of error) :

```
ts-loader: Using typescript@2.1.1 and /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/tsconfig.json
Hash: 3b637fc56087f3ccacc8
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 27898ms
     Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    app.js  915 kB       0  [emitted]  app
index.html    1 kB          [emitted]  
   [0] multi app 52 bytes {0} [built]
  [27] ./src/app/app.module.js 4.55 kB {0} [built]
  [33] ./src/app/request/request.service.js 3.19 kB {0} [built]
  [34] ./src/app/system/system.js 269 bytes {0} [built]
  [63] ./src/app/app.component.js 1.19 kB {0} [built]
  [64] ./src/app/rxjs-operators.js 347 bytes {0} [built]
  [85] ./src/app/app.routing.js 1.4 kB {0} [built]
  [86] ./src/app/login/login.component.js 8.95 kB {0} [built]
  [87] ./src/app/navbar/navbar.service.js 4.25 kB {0} [built]
  [88] ./src/app/account/account.service.js 1.98 kB {0} [built]
  [89] ./src/app/location/location.service.js 2.56 kB {0} [built]
  [90] ./src/app/storage/storage.service.js 6.8 kB {0} [built]
  [91] ./src/app/version/version.service.js 1.4 kB {0} [built]
  [92] ./src/app/download/download.service.js 1.41 kB {0} [built]
  [93] ./src/app/page-dialog/page-dialog.service.js 2.93 kB {0} [built]
  [94] ./src/app/pages/pages.service.js 9.54 kB {0} [built]
 [100] ./src/app/slideshow/slideshow.component.js 2.19 kB {0} [built]
 [101] ./src/app/logout/logout.component.js 2.27 kB {0} [built]
 [102] ./src/app/proceeded-pages/proceeded-pages.component.js 2.92 kB {0} [built]
 [103] ./src/app/pages/pages.component.js 3.38 kB {0} [built]
 [104] ./src/app/planning/planning.component.js 3.05 kB {0} [built]
 [105] ./src/app/planning/planning.service.js 4.04 kB {0} [built]
 [106] ./src/app/init/init.component.js 11.6 kB {0} [built]
 [107] ./src/app/navbar/navbar.component.js 2.54 kB {0} [built]
 [108] ./src/app/page/page.component.js 3.08 kB {0} [built]
 [109] ./src/app/page/page.js 122 bytes {0} [built]
 [110] ./src/app/login/login-form/login-form.component.js 2.87 kB {0} [built]
 [111] ./src/app/login/login.js 203 bytes {0} [built]
 [112] ./src/app/directives/c7z-container.directive.js 1.81 kB {0} [built]
 [113] ./src/app/directives/c7z-full-height.directive.js 1.61 kB {0} [built]
 [114] ./src/app/page-dialog/page-dialog.component.js 4.18 kB {0} [built]
    + 84 hidden modules

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/www/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.d.ts
(122,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Zone'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/www/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.d.ts
(367,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'HasTaskState'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/www/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.d.ts
(376,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TaskType'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/www/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.d.ts
(462,15): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Zone'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/phonegap-plugin-push/index.d.ts
(4,7): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EventResponse'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/phonegap-plugin-push/index.d.ts
(190,3): error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/phonegap-plugin-push/index.d.ts
(250,3): error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(46,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'main' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeModule'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(57,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'parent' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeModule'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(58,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'children' must be of type 'any[]', but here has type 'NodeModule[]'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(78,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'BufferEncoding'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(227,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'errno' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(234,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EventEmitter'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(522,26): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Buffer'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(522,50): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'SlowBuffer'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(543,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EventEmitter'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(543,18): error TS2415: Class 'EventEmitter' incorrectly extends base class 'NodeJS.EventEmitter'.
  Types of property 'eventNames' are incompatible.
    Type '() => (string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type '() => string[]'.
      Type '(string | symbol)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
        Type 'string | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(654,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'httpVersionMajor' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(655,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'httpVersionMinor' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(656,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'connection' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'Socket'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(706,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Agent'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(761,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'addressType' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number | "udp4" | "udp6"'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(764,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Worker'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(1485,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Script'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(2016,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'type' must be of type 'string', but here has type '"udp4" | "udp6"'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(2432,22): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'constants'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(2787,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TLSSocket'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(2984,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'pfx' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | Buffer[]'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(2985,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'key' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | any[] | string[] | Buffer'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(2987,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'cert' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(2988,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'ca' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(2989,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'crl' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string | string[]'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(2991,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'honorCipherOrder' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'boolean'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(2994,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'NPNProtocols' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string[] | Buffer'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(3011,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'key' must be of type 'string | Buffer', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(3013,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'cert' must be of type 'string | Buffer', but here has type 'string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]'.

ERROR in /Users/yolo/Documents/app1/typings/globals/node/index.d.ts
(3014,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'ca' must be of type '(string | Buffer)[]', but here has type 'string | Buffer | (string | Buffer)[]'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say with certainty because I need more of the error log file, but it seems that webpack is compiling typescript definitions from `/node_modules` as well as `typings` as well as your application. Since there are errors about duplicate identifiers, it leads me to think that some definitions are found in both `node_modules` and `typings`. You could try excluding `node_modules` definitions from being compiled and see if that makes a difference. To do so, add the following to `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

Again, I cannot say for certain that this is the issue, it's more of a guess. Also, I am not sure why this would work on windows and not on Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have reinstalled my app, with your changes, and all is fine... I don't know what happened ! But thanks. Only wondering why on Windows I don't have the problem